# Проблема в Visual basic

Tags: visual-basic

```
     Imports System.Math

Module Module1


    Sub Main()
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As String
        Dim y As String
        Console.ReadLine()
        a = Console.ReadLine
        b = Console.ReadLine
        y = Sqrt(Log(a) * Log(b))
        Console.WriteLine(y)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Говорит  Приведение строки "" к типу "Double" является недопустимым.
Хотя ни одного дабла я не вводил.

Comment: Функция `Log()` существует только в варианте `Log(double)` (ну ещё в двухаргументном варианте варианте `Log(Double, Double)`). [Method Math.Log()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.log?view=netcore-3.1). Вы передаёте в качестве аргумента строку - соответственно VB выполняет неявное приведение типа.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim y As String
y = Sqrt(Log(a) * Log(b))
```

А тут вы к чему приводите?

Вы для начала строку в число переведите, потом подсчитайте результат (в виде числа), а потом опять в строку переводите

Comment: Я обучаюсь на 1 курсе, я только начинаю знакомиться с программированием.

Comment: Моя задача сделать мини версию калькулятора, чтобы программа сама считала по формуле из подставленных а и b пользователем